# Binary data from iOS to WebSockets

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, websocket, cocoahttpserver

I am using `CocoaHTTPServer` library and trying to transmit binary data to a web socket. Web socket opens successfully, and can receive strings from iOS without problem. However, when I try to send a binary data through the socket, I get a `Could not decode a text frame as UTF-8` error in Chrome.

Has anyone successfully transferred binary data from iOS through web sockets? (It's a `UIImage` in my case)

`CocoaHTTPServer` has a `sendData:(NSData *)data` method which I'm using but to no success. When I use `sendMessage:(NSString *)` it works without problem (which essentially converts the `NSString` to `NSData` using UTF-8 encoding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it with proper encoding/decoding.

As I understand, `WebSockets` do not support binary data transfer (although I was expecting it would because some tutorials show how to, and they talk about `ArrayBuffer` and `Blob` as the valid data types for binary transfer, which can be set using `connection.binaryType='arraybuffer'`. Maybe it's experimental yet?)

Hence, you need to convert your data into textual data before transmitting through.

In iOS,

```
WebSocket *socket = ...; // From CocoaHTTPServer
NSData *image_data = ...;
NSString *str_64 = [Helper base64ForData:image_data];  // Can be found at http://cocoadev.com/BaseSixtyFour
[socket sendMessage:str_64];
```

in JS,

```
connection.onmessage = function(e)  {
  var msg = e.data;
  var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
  img1.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + msg;
}
```

Tested in Chrome and Safari, works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Beware encoding to base64 is the easy but not necessary the right solution performace wise, you are putting unnecessary processing of encoding and decoding . There  is a livio which is a fork from CoccoaHTTPServer, but it implements the websocket binary send. I dont understand why its is not a plull request, and why it is not mereged into coccoapod, so u need to use Carthage instead of coccoapod.

But as of right now https://github.com/livio/LivioHTTPServer seems to be the answer/

Comment: If you are commenting about the question or about one of the answers, please post a comment, not an answer.